# in Jenkins CI how can I setup a project's build triggers to be optional

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I'm running Jenkins 1.51 and have a Project that will trigger a bunch of other builds once it completes. Is there a way to make these triggers optional so they only run when the user wants them to?

Comment: I'm looking for a way that the user can decide whether or not to activate the triggers when they start the build, they shouldn't have to go into the project's config each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using plugins like [Parametrized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) or [Conditional Build Step Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin).